# How convert 1 year to seconds with Joda-Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

There is [Years](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Years.html) class in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) api,but it does not have any methods for getting seconds or [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) (or any methods about converting it to [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)). Also there is a [DateTimeConstants](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html) with useful constants, but again without any `SECONDS_PER_YEAR` constant.

So how convert 1 year to seconds with joda time?

Comment: First question, is it a leap year?

Comment: What is leap? :) If you ask about days in year it should be 365. Just standard minute, hour and days. It should be `60*60*24*365` seconds in year, but is there a constant for that?

Comment: Yea.  The problem is whether you want the number of seconds in a typical year, or the number f seconds in a given year.  The (obvious) reason that there is no constant is that ... the number of seconds in a year is not constant.  A similar argument goes for Years -> Duration.

Comment: @Cherry:- A [leap year has 366 days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). That is why you have 29 Feb every 4th year :)

Comment: And there's an extra second added once in a while to synchronize with atomic time. http://www.timeanddate.com/time/leapseconds.html

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a constant for the number of seconds in one year because you must first decide a constant for number of days in one year. Using [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) (Java 5+) you could use

```
System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        + TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(6, TimeUnit.HOURS));
System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(366, TimeUnit.DAYS));
```

to get the number of seconds for 365 days (a typical year), 365.25 days (a ["spherical"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) year) and 366 days (a [leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)). I get

```
31536000
31557600
31622400
```

That could be generalized as an `enum` like

```
public enum YEAR {
    TYPICAL(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)), //
    SPHERICAL(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(365, TimeUnit.DAYS) //
        + TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)), //
    LEAP(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(366, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    YEAR(long seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    long seconds;

    public long getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public static YEAR forYear(int year) {
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
            return LEAP;
        }
        return TYPICAL;
    }
}
```

And to test it (and reproduce the same output)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 2016;
    System.out.println(YEAR.forYear(year).getSeconds());
    System.out.println(YEAR.SPHERICAL.getSeconds());
    System.out.println(YEAR.forYear(year + 1).getSeconds());
}
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, this doesn't account for [leap seconds](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/leapseconds.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(   // Assuming generic 24-hour days.
    Year.of( 2018 ).length()                    // Get number of days in year, either 365 or 366 (leap year).
)                                               // Return a `long`, a count of seconds in year assuming 24-hour days.
```

> 31536000

That result is approximate, assuming generic 24-hour days. For a more accurate number, see *Exact number of seconds* section below.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. Note that java.time uses a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), much finer than Joda-Time’s [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Generic number of seconds

If you want a general count of seconds assuming generic 24-hour days, use [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum, [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class, and a little math. This approach ignores leap second.

```
long secondsPerGenericDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds( 1 ) ;  // Assuming 24-hour days.
long days = Year.of( 2018 ).length() ;  // Either 365 or 366 depending on leap year.
long seconds = ( days * secondsPerGenericDay ) ;
```

…or…

```
long secondsInYear = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds( Year.of( 2018 ).length() ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/po2gDY).

> seconds: 31536000 = secondsInYear: 31536000

See also [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294249/642706) by [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch).

## Exact number of seconds

If you want exact number of seconds in a year, that can vary by time zone. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other changes to a zone’s definition made by politicians mean that days can vary in length. They are not always exactly 24 hours in length.

The approach below does ignore [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), when using a common implementation of Java. Leap seconds are unpredictable, so you must look to a historical record if you want to add them into your calculation. In advance, they are scheduled out only a few months.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### `Year`

The `Year` class can assist.

```
Year y = Year.now( z ) ;

LocalDate start = y.atDay( 1 ) ;
LocalDate stop = start.plusYears( 1 ) ;
```

### First moment of the day

We need specific moments to calculate seconds. So need the first moment of each date.

Let java.time determine the first moment. Anomalies such as DST mean the day may start at some time other than 00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = start.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = stop.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

### Elapsed time

We can represent a span of time unattached to the timeline with a resolution of seconds plus fractional second using the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop ) ;
```

Interrogate for the number of whole seconds.

```
long seconds = d.getSeconds() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

> What is leap? :) If you ask about days in year it should be 365. Just standard minute, hour and days. It should be 60*60*24*365 seconds in year, but is there a constant for that?

No there isn't.

And the reason is that the number of days (and hence seconds) in a year is not constant.

Really.

It is either 365 or 366 ... depending on which year you are talking about.

So why didn't they define two constants for the 365 and 366 day cases?  I guess because they deemed it would be harmful.  (For instance, it could lead to people writing applications that assume that *every* year has 365 days ... and get their interval calculations wrong.)

Comment: And also because of leap-seconds!  If they are relevant to you.